# AC electricity. I dont know what happens when thevenergy flows both ways in AC electricity

Tags: electricity

I know that electricity in AC flows both ways but I do not know what happens when it flows both ways. Whats the difference

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I do not know what happens."

Comment: Maybe the assumption in the question is wrong. When feeding a resistive load with AC current, the energy flows always the same direction, since UI = (-U)(-I).

Answer (score 1):

Given the phrasing of your question, I'm going to make a guess and say you're looking for an analogy to make sense of some information that is given to you.

Let's talk about saws, like this chainsaw:

[image: Chainsaw]

Saws always cut by dragging the teeth of the saw across the wood, doing work.  A chainsaw operates analogously to DC.  The motor is applying a force to the chain in one direction, similar to how a DC generator applies a voltage in one direction.  Electrons, like teeth, travel from the high potential to the low potential.  In this chain saw, that means they're always moving in the same direction.

Now let's go old school:

[image: Two man saw]

The two man saw is more like the AC case you're interested in.  The force (analogous to voltage) alternates back and forth as each woodsman takes his turn at pulling on the saw.  The teeth (analogous to electrons) move back and forth doing work each way.

The key to building products that use AC is to make sure that the electrons are not undoing their work when they go the other way.  In the case of saws, it's easy.  You're just trying to rip away at wood -- running the teeth backwards across it doesn't put wood back, it cuts deeper.  When making something like an AC motor, they have to be a bit more careful than that, but rest assured they take care to make sure work gets done in both directions.